# Can I lose the first race?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Is there any way to fail the test where you take the statue from the Loftwing or will none of the other contestants ever reach it?

I've seen them getting close but can they make it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No it isn't possible to lose at all.  The race will only end if you grab the statue or just stop playing the game.

And it would make sense too right?  The game isn't about **Groose** (nor **Cawlin** nor **Strich**), it's about **Link**.  The winner of the race will graduate and get all the goodies that comes with it, there is no second round.  And you can't really progress through the game unless you become a knight so you may leave the grounds.  If you're not, it's pretty much game over and a game over at this point in the game would be too soon.

---

I even started a new game just to test this out.  As already mentioned, it will not end at all until you get the statue.

- Waiting at the start of the race (not diving off the platform to call your **Loftwing**) will go on endlessly.
- It is still possible to dive off the platform, not call your **Loftwing** and get rescued by a knight from the fall but nothing else happens.
- You cannot dive off of your **Loftwing** after you had mounted it.
- You cannot crash at the bottom of the clouds at all.
- You could fly off away from the others and will never be able to go beyond a certain point.  You're all essentially leashed off in a small portion of the sky.
- Doing nothing in either phase of the race (when they start throwing eggs at you) lasts endlessly. I waited approximately 10 minutes in each stage.

There's no way to lose the race even if you wanted to.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting the game would continue. If you lost you'd have to start the race again.

Comment: It was pretty clear (to me) that the winner will be graduating and become a knight.  There's no round 2.  If you were to lose, you couldn't become an knight and wouldn't be able to go on the adventure.  That would essentially be game over and it's far too early in the game for it to end like that so it just goes on until you win.  It's similar to when you first fly your `Loftwing`.  You fall endlessly until you call it so no chance of hitting dirt.

Comment: Yeah, they never come close.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's impossible to fail. The race will not end until you manage to catch the bird.

Answer (score 1):

No. they will never reach the statuette and the race will not end until you grab it.